# Hyper-V: Create DHCP-Server for every network

Tags: networking, hyper-v, windows-10

I want to install some virtual machines like ubuntu and centos on my Windows 10 Hyper-V.

I created a new network switch in Hyper-V only for connections between the Windows Host and the virtual machines - like internal network. I find on all virtual maschines the new interface. To get a connection I want to use a DHCP-Server only for the client subnet like 192.168.100.0/24, but I don't find some DHCP-Server settings for my internal network-switch. My virtual-maschines don't receive an ip configuration above an DHCP-Server, so I must set up a manual IP configration.

Has Hyper-V an option to enable a DHCP-Server for a network-switch or need all virtual maschines a manual IP configuration?

Volker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyper-V virtual switches don't have a DHCP service. You would need to install the DHCP service on a VM that can then offer DHCP services to the virtual network.

hope this helps,

Mike.

Comment: That's really odd because I seem to be sporadically get an address via the Default network... I can't see any DHCP settings either, but I am sure I got one yesterday.

My centos vm apparently decided to reuse the lease...

https://imgur.com/a/SWD5ioc